# In WordPress i18n, what's the difference between "_x" and adding a comment?

Tags: wordpress, internationalization

From what I understand, the `_x()` function is basically `__()` with a "context" parameter to aid translators. But what would be the difference between using `_x()` and using `__()` with a comment? So basically:

```
_x()
```

vs:

```
// translators: blah blah

__()
```

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but I don't I can't explain it better than this guy did http://wpengineer.com/2237/whats-the-difference-between-__-_e-_x-and-_ex/

Comment: Also see [Working with l10n contexts (_x etc)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/119019/12615) and [what's different between _x() and _()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/20779/12615)

Comment: Possible duplicates here at SO: [WordPress l18n _x() function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5802283/1287812) and [poedit doesn't recognize _x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26497272/1287812)

Answer (score 1):

Because a comment is only there to provide information for humans, whereas the context actually affects the uniqueness of the string.

If you look in a PO file you will see a context string might look like this:

```
#. translators: blah blah
msgctxt "button"
msgid "Buy"
msgstr ""

#. translators: another comment
msgctxt "title"
msgid "Buy"
msgstr ""
```

The unique identifier for the first message is `"button\x04Click here"` where `\x04` is a special separator that joins the context and the id. This allows the text "Buy" to be used multiple times where its translation may need to differ. In the second example the English maybe the same, but being a page title and not a button the translation may be different in some languages for grammatical reasons.

Context is often used purely to provide information to translators, but this is not actually its primary purpose.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand now. Google didn't answer my question - you are a godsend